# Segue and displayMessage function not working - Swift 3/4

Tags: ios, swift

Code for registration of user. When the user gets registered, it should go to a new view controller (Home Page in this case) and if username already exists while registration it should display message : Already exists.

Here is the code. No error. User is registered properly, and if username already exists then it returns false response from the api. Just the thing is it doesn't show alert message as required, and doesn't seague if signed up. 'All field are required' and 'Please make sure the passwords match' are displayed, only 'Already exists' doesn't get displayed.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class RegisterUserViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailAddressTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var repeatPasswordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func cancelButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Cancel button tapped")

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func signupButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
       print("Sign up button tapped")


        // Validate required fields are not empty
        if (firstNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
            (lastNameTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
            (emailAddressTextField.text?.isEmpty)! ||
            (passwordTextField.text?.isEmpty)!
        {
            // Display Alert message and return
            displayMessage(userMessage: "All fields are quired to fill in")
            return
        }

        // Validate password
        if ((passwordTextField.text?.elementsEqual(repeatPasswordTextField.text!))! != true)
        {
            // Display alert message and return
            displayMessage(userMessage: "Please make sure that passwords match")
            return
        }


        let params = [

            "first_name"      :  firstNameTextField.text! as Any,
            "last_name"       :  lastNameTextField.text! as Any,
            "email_id"        :  emailAddressTextField.text! as Any,
            "password"        :  passwordTextField.text! as Any,

            ]


        Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request("http://horn.hostingduty.com/api/v1/app_adduser", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .methodDependent))
            .validate(statusCode: [200, 201])
            .responseJSON
            {
                [unowned self] (response) in



                switch(response.result)
                {
                case .success:
                    guard let json = response.result.value as!
                        [String:Any]? else{ return}
                    print("Response \(json)")
                    if let data = json["data"] as! [String:Any]?
                    {
                        let email_id : String = self.emailAddressTextField.text!
                        let userdefault = UserDefaults.standard
                        userdefault.set(self.emailAddressTextField.text, forKey: "email_id")
                        print(email_id)
                        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {

                    let homePage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                    appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = homePage
                        }

                    }

                case .failure:

                        DispatchQueue.main.async
                            {
                        self.displayMessage(userMessage: "Already exists !! ")
                        return
                            }
                }
        }



    }



    func displayMessage(userMessage:String) -> Void {
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {}
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

                let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                    // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
                    print("Ok button tapped")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                alertController.addAction(OKAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.request("http://horn.hostingduty.com/api/v1/app_adduser", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .methodDependent))
        .validate(statusCode: [200, 201])
        .responseJSON
        {
            [weak self] (response) in
            guard let sSelf = self else { return }


            switch(response.result)
            {
            case .success:
                guard let json = response.result.value as!
                    [String:Any]? else{ return}
                print("Response \(json)")
                if let data = json["data"] as! [String:Any]?
                {
                    let email_id : String = self.emailAddressTextField.text!
                    let userdefault = UserDefaults.standard
                    userdefault.set(self.emailAddressTextField.text, forKey: "email_id")
                    print(email_id)
                    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {

                let homePage = sSelf.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomePageViewController") as! SWRevealViewController
                let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
                appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = homePage
                    }

                }

            case .failure:

                    DispatchQueue.main.async
                        {
                    sSelf.displayMessage(userMessage: "Already exists !! ")
                    return
                        }
            }
    }
```

instead of unowned self, take weak refrence of self and then try to get the strong refrence of it in completion handler

also i would like to point out that, the failure to the api call can be because of other reasons too. you can not always assume that the failure was caused because there is already user exist in the system

so try using http response status code or else,

make something like if success

```
{

"code" : "0001", 
"msg" :  "",
"your custom object key here" : {


}
}
```

and incase failure

```
{

"code" : "0000",  // "0000" code can be "0002" if user already exist
"msg" :  "reason for failure",

  }
```

and in success case, check the "code" value

Comment: Appreciate the help. Tried this, but it still doesn't give alert pop up message for user already exists, and still doesnt segue to the next view controller as required. Basically, its the same even after making changes.